# How to resolve "Couldn't export PDF using font 'Arial'" ActiveReports error for reports containing non-ASCII characters

Tags: activereports

Here's the full error message: "Couldn't export PDF using font 'Arial' because characters referencing this font could not be represented with the character encoding 'WinAnsiEncoding'." We're using version 1.3.

This only happens when the report contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.